# App icon disappearing on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, icons, png

My company is having an issue where our iOS App's icon is disappearing sometimes when switching languages.
(Settings - General - International - Language - and change the language.)

Also, there seems to be a situation where sometimes the app icon disappears after updating the app from the AppStore. 
Rebooting the device recovers from the issue and the icon becomes available again, but we have users reporting this issue with negative reviews on the App Store.

It occurs on iOS6 and iOS7 (more frequently on iOS7).

Icons graphical format is properly set as PNG(32bit RGBA), and what's written on Apple's Technical Q&A, QA1686, has been implemented. 
Has Anyone experienced a similar issue? Please advise.

Comment: how you set your app icon ?

Comment: App icon is set in Xcode.
Anything specific you've seen issues with?

Comment: wat name have u given for it, check whether the same name is getting repeated with any other image

Comment: I checked the filenames being used


Application icons are as follows:
icon-60@2x.png
icon-72@2x.png
icon-76@2x.png
icon@2x.png
icon-72.png
icon-76.png
icon.png

So each icon does have a unique filename.
Thank you for the reply, Any other suggestions on what to check?